# Left-aligned input text starting at fixed location

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'm writing an app in Swift 2.2 targeting iOS 8 and using Eureka Forms. For rows of type `TextRow`, I would like to have all of the `textField`s be left aligned starting at a particular distance from the edge of the screen, roughly equal to the width of the longest title. For example:

```
Prompt1          textField
A longer prompt  textField
Prompt2          textField
```

I have found that I can get left alignment with the following code:

```
TextRow.defaultCellUpdate = { cell, row in
    cell.textField.textAlignment = .Left
}
```

For setting the left position, I found that I could use `textFieldPercentage` but it doesn't quite have the behavior I want since the app works in both portrait and landscape. Is there a way to set either the `textField` or title label width to a fixed value?

Comment: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853)

Comment: @Desdenova Are you confident that the only way to achieve what I want is to modify constraints? I was hoping there was a cleaner way that I overlooked.